# Why GOD asked Jewish High Priest to have a Golden Plate with the inscription "HOLINESS TO THE LORD"?

Tags: kohen-priest

Why is the High Priest asked to have a Golden Plate with the inscription "HOLINESS TO THE LORD" worn on his mitre  (Exo. 28:36)? is there any significant meaning in it?

In Exo. 28:38 it says "Aaron shall bear the iniquity committed in the holy things" and "they (Gifts from the People of Israel) may be accepted before the LORD."

Why is this Golden plate described with such impressive lines?

Answer (score 2):

> Aaron shall bear the iniquity committed in the Holy Things

This refers to those sins which are committed *against the holy things* i.e. the sin of a priest entering the Temple and/or officiating in the Divine Service while impure.
See Mishnah, [Menachot 3:3](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.3) and [Zevachim 8:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Zevachim.8) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Hirsch [strikes again](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45342/why-did-god-want-a-tabernacle-built-by-moses/45356?noredirect=1#comment120010_45356)!

On the second verse you quoted (Ex. 28:38), he writes, as part of a much larger discussion on the ציץ:

> ...The כהן גדול (High Priest [who wears the ציץ, *Showplate*]) represents
>   the whole Service of the Sanctuary, and the inscription קדש לה' (holy
>   to God) on his forehead proclaims the Name of God, which expresses the
>   whole essence of the one God in His absolutely free personal being.
>   The Sanctuary is consecrated to Him, and all the sacred things of the
>   Sanctuary are directed to Him.
>
> Hence the ציץ is designed to nullify
>   any defect or impurity these sacred things might suffer in respect to
>   their unswerving direction the one God. The positive proclamation קדש
>   לה' -- which radiates from the forehead of the כהן גדול throughout the
>   Sanctuary and to all its sacred things, inscribing them with the
>   inscription קדש לה' -- can nullify serious errors....

This, I think, about sums up his basic point -- the ציץ is a declaration that everything in the Temple is consecrated to God, and through that it can atone for errors that were made with holy things קדשים in the Temple.
I would recommend reading his whole discussion inside, because there is a lot more elaboration on this topic (and exactly how and for what the ציץ can atone), but this is really the main point of that piece.